# Audio Visualizer with AVQueuePlayer

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avqueueplayer

I'm trying to build a Audio Visualizer when playing from the `AVQueuePlayer`, I want something similar to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios) but `AVQueuePlayer` does not have some of the methods required like `[audioPlayer updateMeters]`, `[audioPlayer numberOfChannels]` and `[audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:]`. Could anyone help me with a workaround to this or link me to a guide to setting up one. I want to use the `AVQueuePlayer` because of the queue ability however if I can't setup something I would consider managing the queue myself and using `AVAudioPlayer`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably your best bet is using it directly and managing the queue yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks, I thought it might be I just thought I should check first. @Linuxios

Comment: Might still be possible, it just seems that that would be easier to me.

Comment: Well I've had a pretty deep look into it and I can't see anything myself. Unless there is some way of calling the `AVPlayer` of the `AVQueuePlayer` since the AVQueuePlayer is just a subclass... @Linuxios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVQueuePlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer, not AVAudioPlayer, which is why it's "missing" those methods.

You can just use AVAudioPlayer for playback and a MPMediaPickerController for loading up a queue of songs. Take a look at the [AddMusic sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). It's a bit dated, but should get you going.